# Load content into div and then access the loaded contents JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm dynamically loading content into a div (which works) but am unable to use the loaded content's JavaScript.

This is my loading code which is called from a clickable unordered list item:

```
<div id="resources" class="tabcontent">
<script>
  $("#resources").load("pages/resources.html");
</script>
</div>
```

Once pages/resources.html has loaded there's a bunch of similar JavaScript within it to load yet more HTML pages into div's within that page.

Answer (score 7):

Just add a callback to the `load()` call:

```
$("#resources").load("pages/resources.html", function() {
  // pages/resources.html has loaded
});
```